Issue with pycharm tolist for user
First time using pycharm now in code to make a chat analyzer but the show chat wt selection for other users doesnt show up
this is the code
enter image description here
checked in blackbox ai and chatgpt no helpenter image description here
only overall is showing when im trying to see show analysis with and other users are not shown

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
